# Export PHP Variable Results To CSV

Tags: php, html, csv, joomla

I am using php to run a SQL Query and populate a HTML Table.  My question is, since I have the $query variable house the sql results, would it be possible to add a button to "Export To CSV" and if the button is clicked it will export a .csv file of the $query that is formatted the same way that the html table that is generated?

Say the query string is like this:

```
$query .= "Select red, green, blue from colorsDB where signoff is not null";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `some_table`'); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
       $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
if ($fp && $result) 
{     
       header('Content-Type: text/csv');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
       header('Pragma: no-cache');    
       header('Expires: 0');
       fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
       {
          fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
           }
    die; 

}
```

Comment: Where in the page would I add this syntax?

Comment: add it after the code which you have posted in the question just replace $result by $query